# new column not added to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a new column to the dataframe with same value for all the rows.

I tried to use `append` method as well as `cbind`.

```
url.data <- read.csv('pathToFile')
url.data <<- append(url.data , 'iOS')
url.data <<- as.data.frame(url.data)
```

Also, I tried this:

```
  cbind(url.data, platform='iOS')
```

None of these works. A new column gets added using Cbind but with N/A for all the values and not iOs.

edit:head(url.data) of the data after trying cbind:

```
  X2016.07.24 None       Mobile_Menu    None.1 N.A X13 N.A.1  X1 X0.0769 X13.1 X1.1
1  2016-07-24 None           Organic      None N/A N/A   N/A 246     N/A     0    0
2  2016-07-24 None googleadwords_int 408578282 N/A  10   N/A   2  0.2000    87    2
3  2016-07-24 None googleadwords_int 408578282 N/A  41   N/A   1  0.0244     8    1
4  2016-07-24 None googleadwords_int 408578282 N/A  28   N/A   4  0.1429    17    2
5  2016-07-24 None googleadwords_int 408578282 N/A  29   N/A   4  0.1379    23    2
6  2016-07-24 None googleadwords_int 408601922 N/A  10   N/A   1  0.1000    17    1
  X1.0000 N.A.2 N.A.3
1  0.0000   N/A   N/A
2  1.0000   N/A   N/A
3  1.0000   N/A   N/A
4  0.5000   N/A   N/A
5  0.5000   N/A   N/A
6  1.0000   N/A   N/A
```

Comment: Could you please show a sample of your data.

Comment: Try this: `url.data$platform<-"iOS"`

Comment: @rar: Thanks. It works. Why did other ones not work?Any idea

Comment: `cbind(url.data, data.frame(platform = rep( "iOS", nrow(url.data) ) ) )`